# Is there possible to know Thread affected memory apart from Main Process memory in linux?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu-16.04

I am working on an operating system of Ubuntu Linux16.04, Compiler is python3.5.2.
In my code, I have generated more than 7 threads using the Threading class of python. Now, the scenario is that my RAM memory increases continuously when code runs. I am got the Process ID of my code from (os.getpid()) functions and using psutil library in python and ps command in Linux, I got the memory usage of my Process(including all threads) but I didn't recognize the memory affected by a particular thread.

when I run my python program, one process is created with several lightweight processes in Linux, Lightweight process ID and number of Lightweight processes is known by ps commands, but still, I did not find any method or tool which can give me memory affected by particular lightweight process(apart from the Main process) in Linux and in python also.

Is there possible to know Thread affected memory apart from Main Process memory in Linux or python?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Compiler is python` - python is a interpreted language, it has an interpreter. But it looks like you are just specifying the python version. `Thread affected memory` - you mean "memory _used_ by thread"? `Lightweight process ID` - how does "Lightweight process" differ from a normal process and what does that mean?

Comment: in Linux, I got a Lightweight processID using the syntax ps -eL in the LWP column.

Comment: Ok, so just to clarify, a long time ago "threads" were called "lighweight processes". Currently a "lightweight process" means the same as "thread".  Just call them "threads". LWP just shows thread id.